# Fast way to delete many, many files?

Tags: windows-vista, temporary-internet-files

My impression is that a subfolder of the Temporary Internet Folder has become really, really bloated.  (Hard for me to say how bloated; the usual user-level tools for calculating disk usage don't stop with an answer in a reasonable amount of time.)

I've gone into the folder in a cmd window and typed

```
del *.*
```

but that seems to take forever, too.  (Meaning, hours.)  I'm pretty sure it's actually deleting things, because I haven't gotten any permissions errors, and free disk space is increasing.

Is there a way to delete all the files more quickly?

Comment: If it's a directory just use `rd /s`.

Comment: You might want to use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) to have this task done quickly for you.